# I'm trying to solve a Frobenius method, Would you lend me some advice? (Differential Equation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm asking again politely. I'm afraid to be blocked by the admin. being blocked is deprivation to learn from my complicated / hard problems that being stuck with by answering it by your knowledge. anyway let this thing over.

I'm solving Frobenius method exercise in number 7, I countered this:

$\ y = x^2y''+ (2x+3x^2)y' -2y $

I tried to solve  the problem by indicial Equation from Frobenius method.

$\ r(r-1)+ p_0r + q_0 $

By this formula, I did this.

I let $\ p_0 = 2 $ while $\ q_0 = 0 $

$\ r^2-r +2r $

then
$\ r^2+r $

$\ r(r + 1) $

the r is zero and negative one

$\ r=0, -1 $

However, I check the answer sheet at back of the book

but the answer of r is different than the one I have solved

$\ r=0, -2 $

the solution or the answer is this.

$\ y_1(x) = \frac {1}{x^2} (2-6x+9x^2), y_2(x) =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1} 3^n x^n}{(n+2+!} $

I solved the $\ y_2 (x) $ and I got it right, however my problem, I'm stuck with 
$\ y_1 (x) $

I try to solve $\ y_1 (x) $

$\ r = -2 $

$\ y'' = x^{n+r} (n+r)^2 - (n+r) $

$\ y' = x^{n+r} (n+r) $

$\ y = x^{n+r} $

$\ y = x^2x^{n+r} (n+r)^2 - (n+r)+ (2x+3x^2)x^{n+r} (n+r) -2 x^{n+r}  $

This brings

$\ y = x^2 x^{n+r-2} (n+r)^2 - (n+r)+ (2x  x^{n+r-1} (n+r) +3x^2 x^{n+r-1} (n+r)) -2 x^{n+r}  $

and

$\ y = x^{n+r} (n+r)^2 - (n+r) + (2 x^{n+r} (n+r) +3x x^{n+r+1} (n+r)) -2 x^{n+r}  $

$\ y = x^{n+r} (n+r)^2 - (n+r) + 2 x^{n+r} (n+r) -2 x^{n+r} + 3x^{n+r+1} (n+r)  $

make $\ 3x^{n+r+1} (n+r) $ to $\ 3x^{n+r} (n+r-1) C_{n-1} $

after that

$\ y = x^{n+r} (n+r)^2 - (n+r) + 2 x^{n+r} (n+r) -2 x^{n+r} C_n + 3x^{n+r} (n+r-1)C_{n-1}  $

all $\ x^{n+r} $ will be collected

$\ y =  x^{n+r} [(n+r)^2 - (n+r) + 2 (n+r) -2 C_n + 3 (n+r-1)C_{n-1} ] $

focus on $\ y =(n+r)^2 - (n+r) + 2 (n+r) -2 C_n + 3 (n+r-1)C_{n-1}  $

substitute $\ r = -2 $

$\ (n-2)^2 - (n-2) + 2 (n-2) -2 C_n + 3 (n-2-1)C_{n-1}  $

then minus $\ - (n-2) + 2 (n-2) $ to bring this

$\ (n-2)^2 + (n-2) -2 C_n + 3 (n-3)C_{n-1}  $

Find the factors of $\ (n-2)^2 + (n-2) -2 $

$\ (n)  (n-3) C_n + 3 (n-3)C_{n-1}  $

distribute n and 3

$\ (n^2-3n) C_n + 3n-9 C_{n-1}  $

Transpose $\ 3n-9 C_{n-1}$

$\ (n^2-3n) C_n = - 3n+9 C_{n-1}  $

divide by $\ (n^2-3n) $ both sides

$\  C_n = \frac{-3n+9 C_{n-1}}{(n^2-3n)}  $

add $\ +n^2-n^2 $

$\  C_n = \frac{-3n+9 +n^2-n^2
 C_{n-1}}{(n^2-3n)}  $

I continue to solve

$\  C_n = \frac{n^2-3n
 C_{n-1}}{(n^2-3n)}+\frac {9-n^2}{n^2 -3n}  $

I ended up like this

$\  C_n = 1C_{n-1}+\frac {9-n^2}{n^2 -3n}  $

I'm stuck, I can't get the right solution
can you help to help me to bridge my solution from the problem into this

$\ y_1(x) = \frac {1}{x^2} (2-6x+9x^2) $

Comment: book is from "Elementary Differential Equation" by C. henry Edwards